# e4 RCP: inject MPerspective into dynamicMenuContribution

Tags: code-injection, e4

I would like to inject the current perspective into my `@AboutToShow` method of the dynamicMenuContribution.

Strangely, it is always null. Although I can inject MWindow and EModelService to get the perspective by:

```
eModelService.getActivePerspective(mWindow);
```

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: I would think that you would have to use @Named(xxx) to get the active perspective in the same way that this is required for the active part or context or shell. However I don't see any name defined for the active perspective so it looks like it is not supported.

Comment: What does your application model look like? For EModelService.getActivePerspective to work, you need to have excactly one MPerspectiveStack as a child of the window you pass as an argument. [If your PerspecticeStack is the only child of your mWindow you could get the active perspective with MPerspectiveStack stack = (MPerspectiveStack)mWindow.getChildren().get(0); MPerspective perspective = stack.getSelectedElement();]